# @Techreport Biblatex - how to include 2 institutions with different locations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am trying to reproduce the following citation in biblatex:

> Alampay, E., Moshi G., Ghosh, I., Peralta, M., Harshanti, J. (2017) The impact of mobile financial services in low- and lower middle-income countries. International Development Research Centre, Ottawa, Canada, and the Department for International Development, UK.

I used the following code:

```
@TechReport{AlampayetalMFSinlowincomecountries2017,\
author = {Alampay, Erwin and  Moshi, Goodiel and Ghosh, Ishita and 
     Lyn, Mina and Peralta, C and Harshanti, Juliana},\
title = {The impact of mobile financial services in low-and 
     lower-middle-income countries}\
year = {2017},\
institution ={International Development Research Centre, Ottawa 
     and the Department for International Development, UK}
}
```

However, like this LaTeX unfortunately doesn't show the institutions (in fact, it doesn't even show the year):
[image: This is what is I get in latex:]

How do I best add the institutions so that they show up?

I am new to LaTeX, so apologies if this is an obvious question :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You have syntax errors in the bib entry. The reason why the `year` field and all subsequent fields aren't showing is because you failed to terminate the preceding field, `title`, with a comma.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you so much, that worked! What difference a little comma can make ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the `year` and `institution` fields aren't showing is because of a syntax error in the field (`title`) that immediately precedes `year`: it wasn't terminated by a comma.

Incidentally, I don't think that `@techreport` is the optimal choice for entry type for this bib entry. Usually, bibliographic items assigned to the `@techreport` entry type feature an "working paper", "discussion paper", "technical report", etc on the title page, and they usually are part of a numbered series. That doesn't seem to apply to the entry at hand. Absent some obviously better choice, I'd use the catch-all entry type `@misc`, and I'd change the `institution` field to `howpublished`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{AlampayetalMFSinlowincomecountries2017,
author = {Alampay, Erwin and  Moshi, Goodiel and Ghosh, Ishita 
     and Lyn, Mina and Peralta, C. and Harshanti, Juliana},
title = {The impact of mobile financial services in low- and 
     lower-middle-income countries},
year = {2017},
howpublished ={International Development Research Centre, Ottawa 
     and the Department for International Development, UK},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```